# Printing out the length of a concatenated string

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
  char a[8] = "hello";
  char b[8] = "HELLO";

  int x = strcmp(a,b);

   printf("%s \n%s \n", a, b); 

  printf("%s\n", strcat(a,b));
  printf("%d", strlen(strcat(a,b)));
}
```

This prints out:

> hello
>
> HELLO
>
> helloHELLO
>
> 12

Why 12?

But if I have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

 void main()
 {
  char a[8] = "hello";
  char b[8] = "HELLO";

  int x = strcmp(a,b);

  printf("%s \n%s \n", a, b); 

  //printf("%s\n", strcat(a,b));
  printf("%d", strlen(strcat(a,b)));
}
```

It prints out:

> hello
>
> HELLO
>
> 10

Could someone explain why the lengths are different here? I have a feeling that it's the '\0' character though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strcat` modifies the string pointed to by the first argument. That is, the string represented by the second argument is appended to the string of the first argument.

Your `char a[8] = "hello";` is 5 characters, plus a null, plus two unused bytes. Then `b` follows it in memory.

Before `strcat:

```
a:  h e l l o \0 _ _
b:  H E L L O \0 _ _
```

After first `strcat`:

```
a:  h  e  l  l  o  H  E  L
b:  L  O  \0 L  O  \0 _  _
```

Now `a` has overwritten into `b`, and `b` points to the string "LO" in essence.

Now the second `strcat` is concatenating "LO" to "helloHELLO". After second `strcat`:

```
a:  h  e  l  l  o  H  E  L
b:  L  O  L  O  \0 \0 _  _
```

Note the length of the string at `a` after the second `strcat` is 12 bytes: "helloHELLOLO".

In your second test case, you eliminated the first `strcat`, so you saw what looks like normal output. But, when you use `strcat` you must make sure your receiving buffer (the first argument) has enough room to hold the entire concatenated string plus null. When using C library functions it's advised to read the manual page. See `man strcat` for details.

Comment: I would just add that calling `strcat` twice with `a` as the first argument, and expecting the result to be the same both times, is also a mistake (although an astute reader will already have drawn that conclusion from your pointing out that `strcat` modifies its first argument).